# How do I make a UIDatePicker display specific dates?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, cocoa, uidatepicker

My application has a need to let the user choose a date from a list of dates conforming to a certain pattern. For instance, they may need to choose a monday from a list Monday's for a month. Is there a way to get a `UIDatePicker` to limit date choices to a certain subset or should I just use a `UIPickerView`?

Comment: You might want to add some of the tag information into the title.  That way when people scan the question list it stands out more.  Good luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot limit which dates are selectable in a `UIDatePicker`. You could change the date when the value changed event is sent, but since the user cannot tell which dates are "good" and which are not, it's a bad UI choice to do so.

Use a `UIPickerView` of your own making instead.

Answer (score 0):

`UIDatePicker` has `minimumDate` and `maximumDate` properties for this purpose. No need to use `UIPickerView` just for this reason.